# Map side join in Hadoop loses advantage data locality?

Tags: hadoop

My Question is related to Map side join in Hadoop.
I was reading ProHadoop the other day I did not understand following sentence

"The map-side join provides a framework for performing operations on multiple sorted
datasets. **Although the individual map tasks in a join lose much of the advantage of data locality**,
the overall job gains due to the potential for the elimination of the reduce phase and/or the
great reduction in the amount of data required for the reduce."

How can it lose advantage of data locality when if sorted data sets are stored on HDFS?Wan't job tracker in Hadoop will run task tracker in on the same on where data set block localize?

Correct my understanding please.

Answer (score 1):

The satement is correct. You do not loss all data locality, but part of it. 
 Lets see how it works:
We usually distinguish smaller and bigger part of the join.
Smaller partitions of the join are distributed to places where corresponding bigger partitions are stored. 
 As a result we loss data locality for one of the joined datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what does David mean, but to me, this is because you have only map phase, then you just go there and finish your job by bring different tables together, without any gains about HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

This is the process followed in Map-side join:

1. Suppose we have two datasets R and S, assume that both of them fit into the main memory. R is large and S is small.
2. Smaller dataset is loaded to the main memory iteratively to match the pairs with R.

In this case, we achieve data locality for R but not S.